# Checkbox submission to display text?

Tags: checkbox, concrete5

Thank you for your help ahead of time.

I created an office hours block in Concrete5. Some departments aren't open on certain days, so I'm trying to make a checkbox that if checked displays "Closed" rather than the office hours. Here is an example for Sunday:

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <?php  echo $form->label("Sundayclosed", t("Sunday (close)")); ?>
        <?php  echo (isset($btFieldsRequired) && in_array('Sundayclosed', $btFieldsRequired) ? '<small class="required">' . t('Required') . '</small>' : null); ?>
            <?php  echo $form->text("Sundayclosed", $Sundayclosed > 0 ? date("g:i A", $Sundayclosed) : null, array ('autocomplete' => 'off', )); ?>
</div>
```

My code works and displays the open and closing time set in the block. However, I'm not sure how to go about adding a checkbox to display "Closed" rather than the time set in the block.

Would anyone mind helping me out? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well the piece of code you provided, That's a text box where you input closing time for Sunday and what you would like is a checkbox, on top of the text box, no instead of it, to signal that the shop is closed on sundays and that will show "closed" on your site if closed.

So first, in your block settings you need to add the checkbox:

```
<?php  echo $form->label("SundayTotallyClosed", t("Sunday (totally close)"));

echo $form->checkbox("SundayTotallyClosed", 1, $SundayTotallyClosed); ?>
```

Then in your blocks view, where you want the "closed" to show:

```
<?php if ($SundayTotallyClosed) {
    echo "Closed";
} else {
    // put here the code that normally shows the closing time
}
```

Be careful when saving your settings, a checkbox send a value to be saved only if it's checked, otherwise nothing is sent. The problem is if you checked and saved it, a value of 1 is saved. If later you uncheck it and save, nothing is sent so nothing is saved so the value remains 1.

The way to deal with that when saving is to make sure you have:

```
$SundayTotallyClosed = SundayTotallyClosed ? 1 : 0;
```

And then save it normally